# Is there a macro to list spaces for which a user has admin permissions?

Tags: permissions, confluence

This would be useful when needing to make changes to spaces in bulk or batches. The [Spaces List Macro](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/spaces-list-macro-139375.html) doesn't have a permissions or user parameter.